# ¿Cómo generar permutaciones desde una lista, pero solo de alguno de sus elementos?

Tags: python

Puedo generar permutaciones, por ejemplo, una con 4 elementos

```
import itertools`

list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Al hacer esto se computan todas las combinaciones posibles.
Pero mi duda es como puedo dejar fijo un elemento al hacer las permutaciones, por ejemplo, que quede fijo el numero 2 en el segundo puesto y sacar todas las combinaciones de esa lista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay forma directamente desde `permutations`, pero nada te impide calcular las permutaciones solo por los valores que no son el valor fijo, es decir `[1,3,4]` y luego agregar el valor fijo a cada una de las tuplas generadas:

```
import itertools

fixed_val = 2   
lista=[(c[0], fixed_val, c[1], c[2]) for c in itertools.permutations([1, 3, 4])]
print(lista)

[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1)]
```

La única limitación te la da la cantidad de elementos de la permutación, Si tienes muchos elementos en tu lista inicial, la cantidad de elementos de tu lista crecerá exponencialmente, lo cual podrá agotar la memoria o los recursos de la CPU.